# A question which might fit in Ask Ubuntu, here or SuperUser

Tags: discussion, scope

I've just posted this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250035/how-can-i-prevent-my-browser-from-hogging-all-system-resources

on the main site, but I'm not really sure whether this is the right place for it, or rather Super User; the thing is, while I'm running Linux, it's not entirely a Linux-y issue, and you get the same problem on other operating systems as well. And, actually, I'm running Ubuntu, so in the other direction you could say it's Ubuntu-specific enough to ask there.

How do I call this?

Comment: I think if your question is closely specific to a software, then Suer User is a good choice (Example:[this](http://superuser.com/q/945924)) but If It also deals with Linux OS (as I think your may be), U & L is a good choice!

Comment: ["Super User" it is](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I don't really follow, can you elaborate some more?

Comment: I think @Peter was just making a joking reference to muru's edit to your question, which (among other things) changed "superuser.SX" to "Super User". As the last section of that link instructs:

"As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written 'Stack Overflow' (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always written stackoverflow.com (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply). Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc."

Answer (score 12):

Your question does fit the scope of all three sites, since you are using Ubuntu, so it's up to you to decide where to ask. Ubuntu questions are not unwelcome here, Linux questions are not unwelcome on Super User.

You're right that the question could be asked about other OSes, but... **your** question isn't asking about other OSes. Let's cross that bridge when we get to it.

As far as I can tell, questions are only migrated to Ask Ubuntu if they are so specific to Ubuntu as to not be valid for other distributions, or it fits Ask Ubuntu's scope but doesn't fit here. (But then, I have seen such a migration happen only twice, I think.) So, the question fits here just fine.

Comment: That third paragraph is the useful part of your answer to me :-)